# Ho to refresh the Spring when I add new job

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an issue with spring boot, my project is about executing .bat file in a specific date but the problem is that the file isn't executed until I restart spring boot.
when I add a new job from Angular it might not be loaded in my spring application.. but when I restart my application is loaded. How can I resolve this issue?
Please help me.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer, DisposableBean {
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

@Autowired
private TaskRepository repository;

@Autowired
private ListeExecJobRepository rep;

@Autowired
private FichierRepository frepo;

@Autowired
private TaskService service;

@Override
public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {

List<Task> tasks = repository.findAll();
tasks.forEach(t -> {
    ListeExecJob liste= new ListeExecJob();
    liste.setDate_creation(new Date());
    if (t.getActive()==true) {
        liste.setDate_execution(new Date());
    Runnable runnableTask = () -> executeBatFile(t.getScript(), liste);
    Trigger trigger = new Trigger() {
        @Override
        public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
            CronTrigger crontrigger = new CronTrigger(t.getCronExpression());
            return crontrigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
        }
    };
    taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(runnableTask, trigger); 
    }
    liste.setTask(t);
    rep.save(liste);
    });
     }
    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
    if (executor != null) {
    executor.shutdownNow();
    }
    }
    public void executeBatFile(String filePath, ListeExecJob liste) {
    try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().
       exec("cmd /c " + filePath);
    liste.setStatus("succès");
    liste.setFin_execution(new Date());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    liste.setStatus("échoué");      
    }
    rep.save(liste);
    }
    @Bean
    public ScheduledExecutorService executor(){
    return executor;
     }
    @Bean
    public ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar(){
     return new ScheduledTaskRegistrar();
      }
     }
```

And this in the service

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
@Primary
  public class TaskService {

 @Autowired
 private TaskRepository repository;

 @Autowired
 private ListeExecJobRepository rep;

  @Autowired
  private ListeExecJobService service;

  @Autowired
  private ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar;

  @Autowired
  private SchedulerConfig sc;

  @Autowired
   private ScheduledExecutorService executor;

   @Autowired
   public TaskService(TaskRepository repository) {
  super();
  this.repository = repository;
 this.taskRegistrar = new ScheduledTaskRegistrar();
  }
    public List<Task> listAllTask() {
  return repository.findAll(); 
  }
   public Task addTask(Task task) {
 ListeExecJob liste = new ListeExecJob();
 List<ListeExecJob> a =task.getListe();
 repository.save(task);
 for (Iterator iterator = a.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    ListeExecJob e = (ListeExecJob) iterator.next();
    e.setTask(task);
 }
 service.updateList(a);
 liste.setTask(task);
 rep.save(liste);
 repository.save(task);
 return task;
   }
 .......
 }

enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: You haven't set any method with the @Scheduled annotation so it won't run it on a schedule.Try following a simple example from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

Comment: i did a dynamic execution  from angular, when I add a new job from Angular it not be loaded in my spring application.. but when I restart the Spring is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call it manually inside `addTask`:

```
public Task addTask(Task task) {
    ListeExecJob liste = new ListeExecJob();
    List<ListeExecJob> a = task.getListe();
    repository.save(task);
    for (Iterator iterator = a.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
         ListeExecJob e = (ListeExecJob) iterator.next();
         e.setTask(task);
    }
    service.updateList(a);
    liste.setTask(task);
    rep.save(liste);
    repository.save(task);
    //manually call your function here
    sc.configureTasks(this.taskRegistrar)
    return task;
}
```